# Git Push Error - Could not resolve host name

Tags: git, push

```
nshastri@N-SHASTRI ~/datasciencecoursera (master)
$ git push origin master
```

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname https: no address associated with name
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Comment: so, what's your actual question?

Comment: `maaster` will be `master`????

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Simply type:

```
git remote -v
```

and double-check the url associated with `origin` for your [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309).

Once you have the right url, update your remote origin with another [`git remote` command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote):

```
git remote set-url origin /the/right/url
```

In your case, the url is wrong:

```
https:/github.com/nkshastri/datasciencecoursera.git
# instead of:
https://github.com/nkshastri/datasciencecoursera.git
     ^^^^
```

Simply type:

```
git remote set-url origin https://nkshastri@github.com/nkshastri/datasciencecoursera
```

Then try again:

```
git push -u origin master
```

(with `master`, not `maaster`)

Comment: Thanks for help I tried doing it and still no success. I am posting a screen shot for reference.

Comment: @NarendraKumarShastri what os and git version are you using?

Comment: My os is windows 7 Git bash version is version 1.9.4-preview20140815

Comment: @NarendraKumarShastri what is the output of `git remote -v` (no screenshot, just the text)

Comment: I am not able to post sceen shot so output is:nshastri@N-SHASTRI ~/datasciencecoursera (master)
$ git remote -v
origin  https:/github.com/nkshastri/datasciencecoursera.git (fetch)
origin  https:/github.com/nkshastri/datasciencecoursera.git (push)

Comment: @NarendraKumarShastri Perfect, the text output is always better than a picture. I have edited my answer, and suggested a solution.

Comment: I am not able to execute push command as I am receiving error as ssh: Could not resolve hostname https: no address associated with name
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @NarendraKumarShastri if you see "https", it is not an error 'as ssh' (it has nothing to do with ssh). Simply type the `git remote set-url` I suggest in my answer, then try again.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I am able to change the origin however I am still not able to push getting following error:

Comment: nshastri@N-SHASTRI ~/datasciencecoursera (master) $ git push -u origin master Password for 'https://nkshastri@github.com': To https://nkshastri@github.com/nkshastri/datasciencecoursera.git ! [rejected] master -> master (fetch first) error: failed to push some refs to https://nkshastri@github.com/nkshastri/datasciencecoursera.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do hint: not have locally.

Comment: This is usually caused by another repository pushing hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: @NarendraKumarShastri sure, do a `git pull --rebase` first. Then push.

Comment: @NarendraKumarShastri see more at https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-pull/#pulling-via. The other option would be to make sure you create an **empty** repo on GitHub

Comment: Getting following error: failed to push some refs to 'https://nkshastri@github.com/nkshastri/datasciencecoursera.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: @NarendraKumarShastri that seems to be an entirely **unrelated** question. Please make it an independent question, and accept the current answer for the current question (the one at the top of the page, the one you initially asked)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am able to sync and push my work to repo. Thanks for all your support. I accept the answer for current question. No more issues. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes this can be caused by a network issue. Try restarting your wifi or, if the repository is behind a VPN, make sure you are on the VPN.

Comment: occured after restarting the server..disabling/enabling wifi on my mac solved it for now :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to connect a FALSE NAME DIR
your repository name should be the SAME as your folder name in local environment.

git repo: gitRepo
folder name: gitRepo
now you can push

it is also a good practice to first CLONE your new repository to a different folder and then you can COPY your code to this new folder and then change its name to the right git repository name.

Answer (score 0):

For me in `~/.git-credentials` I have two credential is has been stored. 
So I keep one that I want to interact now push, pull working fine.

For more information about git-credentials follow this [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is applicable only for small projects...

To get around this... I created a new directory with files having the same name as in the old directory.

Simply copy-pasted the code from old files to the corresponding files of the new directory...

Then did the usual command chain...

```
git remote add URL_OF_YOUR_REPO
git branch -M main
git status
git add .
git commit -m "Problem Solved!"
git push -u origin main
```

Didn't face any error after this. Useful for small repos.