# Unable to push from local Desktop to github

Tags: git, github, push

Unable to push error **fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user/repository.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com**
I have No problem in cloning, and also no problem in pushing from one of my repository. How can I smoothly push from all my repository.

Comment: what code did you use to do the pushing?

Answer (score 0):

As I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25932311/6309), in that specific repository, do a `git remote -v` to check what remote URL you are using.

And you can compare that URL with the one used in another local repository from which you can push.
That way, you can infer why this particular repository cannot push.

The [OP pradeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15589787/pradeep) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67110043/unable-to-push-from-local-desktop-to-github/67120691#comment119501607_67120691):

> I could push successfully after uninstalling Git and then reinstalling it.

Comment: Problem resolved and I could push successfully after uninstalling  git and then reinstalling

Comment: @pradeep Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.